# Terminal is access denied of flutter sdk path variable .zshrc file

Tags: macos, flutter, terminal

Wrote path for `flutter SDK` with `$HOME/.zshrc` and with `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/prettygirl/FlutterSDK/flutter/bin"`

It went ok and even the `flutter doctor` worked.

Then when I close the `terminal` and reopen it, then it shows `.zshrc permission denied`, but I have given `full disk access` to the `terminal`.

`/Users/prettygirl/.zprofile:export:1: not valid in this context: PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/prettygirl/FlutterSDK/flutter/bin /Users/prettygirl/.zshrc:1: permission denied: /Users/prettygirl/FlutterSDK/flutter/bin`

now when I run `flutter doctor` it says `zsh: command not found: flutter` like I never updated the SDK path.

Opened `.zshrc` file with `a text editor`and it contains the path and opens fine.

Why is that?

Comment: in termial fire command  "echo $path" your path is showing or not?

Comment: @RohitChaurasiya first time shows the full path and even runs the `flutter doctor`, the second time (when terminal is reopened) it only shows those `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin` Only.

Comment: you need to open .zshrc file add those line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set the SDK path in the .zshrc file

open .zshrc file

```
vim .zshrc
```

add a line on this file

```
export PATH="$PATH:[PATH_OF_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/bin"
```

close terminal and reopen the terminal check

```
echo $path
```

if a path is showing then try other commands related to flutter.

```
 flutter doctor
```

Comment: it works thanks :)

Comment: Welcome and thanks for your response